# interpolating a data along y axis at points defined along x axis

Tags: matlab

Due to lack of explaining i am going to edit my question a bit. 
I have a data set along y axis plotted against x axis with step of 0.01 along x axis. Of course along y axis the step can be any arbitrary value. For example i have 0.02 and 0.03 then 0.05. Which means value 0.04 is  missing along y axis. I want to interpolate this and values like this.

Please help me out.

Data: (Its just part of data, Actuall data goes till 1 in both columns)

```
0 0.154994
0.01 0.161559
0.02 0.16794
0.03 0.168151
0.04 0.172584
0.05 0.177927
0.06 0.187229
0.07 0.194835
0.08 0.195799
0.09 0.200876
0.1 0.207076
0.11 0.213972
0.12 0.220275
0.13 0.227207
0.14 0.234465
0.15 0.238785
0.16 0.250232
0.17 0.257551
```

Comment: You probably want to use [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html) for this.

Comment: i did but somehow not working

Comment: please temperce consider the edited question and help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Following what @tmpearce said, the simplest use would be something like:

```
>> x = 0.0:0.01:0.17;
>> pred_y = interp1(Data(:,1), Data(:,2), x);
```

Edit follows:

If you data you posted is named `Data`, and your `x` and `y` data exist on `{0,1}` you might want to do this:

```
>> X = Data(:,1);
>> Y = Data(:,2);
>> pred_x = 0.0:0.01:1.0;
>> pred_y = interp1(X,Y,pred_x);
```

See the literature on [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp1.html) for all of the options.

Comment: Actually the left column goes till 1.0. And i tried to load the right column by load command

Comment: i tried X=0.0:1.0  ,    xi=0.0:0.01:1.0  ,  yi=interp1(yi,X,xi)

Comment: The size of the grid point arrays should match the size of the value arrays. Its the message i get every time

Comment: please consider the edited question as it explains the case better